# Windows directory with no permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2008, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I accidentally removed all permissions from a directory on a Windows 2008 server. I can see the directory when listing contents of its parent both through Windows Explorer and DOS, but I can't do anything else. No matter what I try, the system essentially acts like I'm trying to work with a directory that doesn't exist. Trying to change the permissions through Windows Explorer yields a message that the security information is not available (on the Security tab). I've also tried `takeown` and modifying permissions with `icacls`, both of which report file not found. My account is part of the `Administrators` group. The account that created the folder (the owner before I messed up the permissions) can't even see the directory when listing contents of its parent. `dir /q` reports the owner of the directory as "...". Is there anything that can be done here or is this directory lost?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to log in using the local administrator account and run `takeown /F` on the directory in question. From there, I was able to reset the permissions of the directory and all of its contents.